# Recover a file which has lost 5 minutes ago

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, database, sqlite

Is it possible to recover a file which removed 5 minutes ago? I was working with `sqliteman` and suddenly it saved an empty database on my database file.

It would be greatly appreciated if you suggest any solution. 
Note: I'm on 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using hdd (instead of ssd) you can recover it using "photorec".
Install it: `sudo apt-get install testdisc` then run `photorec`.

[image]
ps.: depending on the size of your disk it can takes a lot of time, and you will recover a lot of files.